# onClick method not called on Android

Tags: android, onclick

I am doing the simplest of onClick models and cannot get the onClick method to fire.  I know it is something simple, and I am new to Android.  Any help is appreciated.

```
package com.bordeloniphone.timeentry;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TimeEntryActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button okButton;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        okButton.setText(":)");
        okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //setContentView(okButton);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("TEST", "TEST");
        Toast.makeText(this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Here is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your exact code into a new project and it worked. I get the toast and LogCat entry. What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: Your code works fine for me..Check after clean and build your project..

Comment: Yes, this code works for me. Maybe you can try: Toast.makeText(TimeEntryActivity.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 7):

After much angst and gnashing of teeth, I figured it out.  I had to delete the emulator device and add an new one and now it works like a champ.   I appreciate everyone trying to help.

Comment: Wow. So, if someone were to have this issue on a physical device, it might get interesting. That's why I'm here, actually. I have a case of a click handler just not being called (one of many that do work). Cleaning and installing hasn't helped. I was hoping for more robust solutions. Maybe I'm holding it wrong...

Answer (score 6):

Instead of setting the onClicklistener to this, try this approach:

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("TEST", "TEST");
            Toast.makeText(this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I never actually said it wasn't.

Comment: If you agree his way is valid, then how does your answer help his problem?

Comment: As he stated he is new to Android, I think pointing out the generally more accepted solution to setting up an onClickListener is helpful.

Comment: I disagree that this way the generally more accepted solutions. Doing it this way totally eliminates reusability and greatly blots your code size once you have several different listeners. While I've seen this a lot, I feel it's the easy way out. I prefer implementing an onClickLister and using that same listener for all my views and then doing a switch case on my view id to know what action to perform. This is much cleaner and keeps all your actions in one place.

Comment: I agree that this is generally the more accepted way. It more reusable (try moving a handler between fragments using one big switch statement), the code is right where it needs to be, and in the vast majority of cases simply calls a helper method to perform any heavy lifting.

Comment: This actually solved my problem, so this is a perfectly valid answer.  I defined my click listener as a final instance variable, but due to the design of my parent class, the instance class was not created by the time I was trying to set it as a listener.  Changing it from an instance variable to an anonymous inner class solved my problems.

Answer (score 4):

You should try Cleaning your project or try to restart your Eclipse or any other Editor you are using as it is a valid code and should work fine.

**UPDATE:**

Also, you should check your Logcat, are you getting the output of  `Log.d("TEST", "TEST");` because your Toast seems to be implemented in a wrong manner.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // wrong
Toast.makeText(Activity_name.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // correct
```

Using `this` in Toast inside the Listener means you are Referencing the Listener, which indeed should not be the case. You have to reference to the Activity itself so better use `Activity_name.this`.

Answer (score 0):

Button iv_StyleInspiration_Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iv_StyleInspiration_Back);
iv_StyleInspiration_Back.setOnClickListener(this);

Try this Whenever you implement onclick in your activity you need to set as above to make it work for all controls and onclick should look something as below

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View pView) {
        if (null != pView) {
            switch (pView.getId()) {
                case  R.id.iv_StyleInspiration_Back:
                    //do what you want
                                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check for Three Steps:

1. find the button by id correctly
2. link the button to a listener. (adding the actionListener)
3. you specify a condition for this button in case of implementing an actionListener class.

Answer (score -2):

try making the button clickable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:clickable="true" />
```