# When click on the button the application crash

Tags: java, android

I'm new with android and I have created a new activity with some radio buttons, but when I click on the button the application crash and It give me some errors, I tried to find some information on some errors but I can't find the problem.

This is my XML Code

> ```
> <TextView 
>     android:text="@string/gps_location"
>     android:id="@+id/lbl_gps_location"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
>
> <EditText 
>     android:id="@+id/txtGpsLocationEntry"
>     android:hint="@string/gpsLocationHint"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/lblAmountTraffic"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
>     android:text="@string/amount_traffic"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
>
> <RadioGroup 
>     android:id="@+id/rbAmountTraffic"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>
>   <RadioButton
>       android:id="@+id/rbModerate"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:text="@string/moderate" />
>
>       <RadioButton
>       android:id="@+id/rbHeavy"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:text="@string/heavy" />
>
>   <RadioButton
>       android:id="@+id/rbStandstill"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:text="@string/standstill" />
> </RadioGroup>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/lblDirections"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
>     android:text="@string/directions"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
>
> <RadioGroup 
>     android:id="@+id/rbDirections"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>
>   <RadioButton
>       android:id="@+id/rbNorth"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:text="@string/north" />
>
>       <RadioButton
>       android:id="@+id/rbSouth"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:text="@string/south" />
> </RadioGroup>
>
> <Button 
>     android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="@string/submit" 
>     android:onClick="insertTrafficData"/>
>  </LinearLayout>
> ```

This is my activity code

```
double latitude;
    double longitude;
    LatLng location;
    Geocoder geocoder;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_accident);

        //Get action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Enabling up/ Back navigation

        // show the action bar
        actionBar.show();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        latitude = bundle.getDouble("latitude");
        longitude = bundle.getDouble("longitude");

        location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

        try {

             List<Address> addresses;
             geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
             addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

             String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
             String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
             String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

             EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtGpsLocationEntry);
            text.setText(address + " " + city + " " + country);


            TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_gps_location);
            text2.setText(address + " " + city + " " + country);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), address + " " + city + " " + country, 2).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void insertTrafficData(View view){

        try{

            DBTraffic db = new DBTraffic();

            RadioButton amountTraffic = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbAmountTraffic);
            RadioButton direction = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbDirections);

            db.insertTraffic(getApplicationContext(), location, amountTraffic.toString(), direction.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And these are the errors:

```
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method InsertTrafficData(View) in the activity class com.example.maltatraffic.AddTraffic for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnSubmit'
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3601)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4107)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17160)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: InsertTrafficData [class android.view.View]
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
01-02 20:05:49.411: E/AndroidRuntime(25558):    ... 11 more
```

Can please someone help me.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: Yes I did clean the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are a bunch of buggy problems with using the XML to define an onClick method. I would suggest two possible solutions:

- According to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365285/onclick-method-not-called-on-android) you should try cleaning the project in Eclipse. If that doesn't work, they said the final solution was to delete the emulator to get it working.
- The other solution would be to implement a onClick handler in the onCreate method of the activity for the button. [An example is shown here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243704/using-onclick-attribute-in-layout-xml-causes-a-nosuchmethodexception-in-android)

Comment: I've been using onClick in XML for years -- are there platform problems, or are they IDE-specific?

Comment: According to the the answers above, they are IDE-specific, thus the need to delete the emulator.

Comment: I'm testing the application on my mobile

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're defining an onClick() in your xml that doesn't match a method in your Activity. Did you define InsertTrafficData(View) in com.example.maltatraffic.AddTraffic?

I looked closer, it looks like in XML you use 'InsertTrafficData' but in your activity it's 'insertTrafficData'. Those must be identical, check your case.

Comment: Looks the same in the XML you posted, but not in the error... Double check that you're looking at the correct layout file and that it's truly cased as described.

Comment: @user2427819, do a case-insensitive search for InsertTrafficData... I'm guessing there is a case mismatch somewhere -- also try renaming the method in both places and check the logcat output again.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of exceptions, you should implement `onClickListener` and override the `onClick` function, than assign listener to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Java is case-sensitive in your code the method is starts with lower-case:

```
insertTrafficData(View)
```

and on XML you have (I guess):

```
InsertTrafficData(View)
```